# Accessing the cluster application using api server address on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, kubernetes-apiserver

I am a little confused about API server address host that is provided by AKS why am i not able to access the cluster application via the api server address or is there any way i can do that?? I know we can always use LoadBalancer or a NodePort service to access any application inside the cluster externally, but can we do that with the API server address as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, with the API server address you can not access your application.

You only can access the Pod or the Service (just use type `ClusterIP` to not create an Azure LoadBalancer) from inside you cluster. For external access you would need an [ingress-controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) combined with a Service type `LoadBalancer`.

You could use the [API server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/) to create, read, update & delete Kubernetes resources like services, pods, deployments, secrets etc.